# Why cannot I change a collection returned by getter?

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have a class with a getter that returns its private field List.

```
Class MyClass {
  private List<String> myList;

  public List<String> getMyList(){
    return myList;
  }
}
```

But the caller of the getter method cannot add or remove elements from that List.

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
List<String> hisList = instance.getMyList();
hisList.add("new element");
```

UnsupportedOperationException was thrown.

I know that getter returns a reference to that list, but why is that list read-only at caller side? Note I have not returned Collections.unmodifiableList() in the getter.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I created a fix-sized list by Arrays.asList, that why ;)

Comment: That all looks correct... is there code missing? I don't see the list initialized any wheres....

Comment: We don't have the code necessary to answer your question. You haven't shown us how myList was instantiated. If I ran the code you have supplied us, I would get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Initialisation code, and first couple lines of the stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you haven't called `unmodifiableList()` in the `getter`, but the list could *already* be unmodifiable as referenced by `myList`.

It would help if you could provide a short but *complete* example (e.g. one which populates `myList` :)

Comment: It would be also very interesting how you instantiate the list

Comment: Also possibly `Arrays.asList` (which gives mutable but not "structurally" changeable `List`).

Answer (score 4):

You are probably creating an unmodifiable or constant List as in:

```
myList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", ...);  // returns a fixed-size list
```

*only guessing without seeing the code that creates the List...*